# Safest way to get User Id in AngularFire2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I'm having a little problem figuring out which is the safest way to obtain an authenticated user's `uid` in AngularFire2. I have noticed that there are 2 ways of achieving this. I am not sure which is the safest way to obtain it, incase one of the ways has an issue/certain conditions that must be met prior.

Method 1: **Use the auth variable**

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
    let uid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid
}
```

Method 2: **Subscribe**

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
    let uid = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => user.uid)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like this for method 2.

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if(user) {
      this.uid = user.uid;
    } else {
      // Empty the value when user signs out
      this.uid = null;
    }
  });
}
```

In this case, it would be better than method 1. Currently you're setting the var "uid" to a subscription, not the actual uid value. I also added a check to make sure user exists before accessing the uid property.

The problem with the first option would be that if the user logs out and back in as a different account, the uid will remain the same. That latter subscribes to the auth state, so you will not get this problem.

Hope this helps!